# How to migrate MYSQL 5.7 to 8 without recreate table with dangling FULLTEXT index?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to upgrade my RDS MySql from version 5.7 to 8 but I'm getting errors the precheck log that tell me I have issues with the fulltext index.
I tried to delete the fulltext index but I'm still getting this error:

> Table `xxxx` contains dangling FULLTEXT index. Kindly recreate the
> table before upgrade.

It's really big table and I can't recreate it so easy.

Can someone have a workaround I can use without the need to recreate this table?

Thanks

Comment: Voting to move this question to dba.stackexchange.com, because it is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

This is an error specific to AWS Aurora. It is not a MySQL error (I searched the MySQL source tree and there is no occurrence of the word "kindly").

This AWS documentation page describes the error: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.mysql80-upgrade-procedure.html

Their recommended fix:

> First, we go back to the original cluster. Then we run `OPTIMIZE TABLE tbl_name [, tbl_name] ...` on the tables causing the following error:
>
> ```
> Table `tbl_name` contains dangling FULLTEXT index. Kindly recreate the table before upgrade.
> ```

They also describe creating a new, empty table, and copying the old data to the new table. This is nearly the same operation, and takes just as long.